# How to access Winston output from within Jest test

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, jestjs, winston

UPDATE: I believe I have found a (probably hacky) way to solve both problems, will post my updated code and solutions tomorrow for anyone interested.

I am trying to create a CLI application and decided I wanted to format the log output for a better user experience, including adding a verbose mode. I thus installed winston and managed to get it working how I wanted to. I then installed jest as I the app is getting more complex so I wanted to automate testing. I decided to make my first test for the logger as it was the last thing I was working on and I have immediately run into problems. My plan was to count the lines of output from the console log and check they were equal to ten: this would then mean I wouldn't have to hardcode in any error specific error messages which may change if I decide to change the log formatting at a later date. I would also like a test that changes the environment variable from dev to prod to ensure that it works correctly in both environments: does anyone know if this is possible? I am currently using dotenv for managing my environment variables and have added the relevant code to my jest config file so it will read the variables correctly. I have been reading through various stack overflow posts and the jest docs about mock functions in an attempt to solve these problems but it is all flying over my head. I don't strictly need these test to work to get on with my app as I'm pretty confident it is all working fine but it is frustrating to not be able to solve these problems and it would be useful to know in the future in case I do need to make a test that relies on the log output. Can anyone help?

set-log-to.js

```js
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, printf, errors } = format;

const nodeEnvironment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const cc = require('../constants/chalk-classes');
const {
  fatal,
  caveat,
  victory,
  error,
  warn,
  attempt,
  success,
  info,
  debug,
  plain,
} = cc;

const config = {
  levels: {
    fatal: 0,
    caveat: 0,
    victory: 0,
    error: 1,
    warn: 2,
    attempt: 3,
    success: 3,
    info: 3,
    verbose: 4,
    debug: 5,
  },
};

const formatting = combine(
  errors({ stack: true }),
  printf((infoObj) => {
    const { level, message } = infoObj;
    switch (level) {
      case 'fatal':
        return `${fatal(`${level}:`)} ${plain(message)}`;

      case 'caveat':
        return `${caveat(`${level}:`)} ${plain(message)}`;

      case 'victory':
        return `${victory(`${level}:`)} ${plain(message)}`;

      case 'error':
        return `${error(`${level}: ${message}`)}`;

      case 'warn':
        return `${warn(`${level}: ${message}`)}`;

      case 'attempt':
        return `${attempt(message)}`;

      case 'success':
        return `${success(message)}`;

      case 'info':
        return `${info(message)}`;

      case 'verbose':
        return `${plain(message)}`;

      case 'debug':
        return `${debug(level)}: ${plain(message)}`;
    }
  })
);

function setLevel(level) {
  if (!level) {
    if (nodeEnvironment === 'dev') {
      return (level = 'debug');
    } else {
      return (level = 'warn');
    }
  } else {
    return level;
  }
}

function setLogTo(level) {
  level = setLevel(level);
  const log = createLogger({
    levels: config.levels,
    level,
    transports: [
      new transports.Console({
        format: formatting,
      }),
    ],
  });
  return log;
}

module.exports = setLogTo;
```

set-log-to.test.js

```js
const setLogTo = require('../set-log-to');

test('All log levels function correctly', () => {
  let log = setLogTo('debug');
  log.fatal('This is fatal');
  log.caveat('This is a caveat');
  log.victory('This is a victory');
  log.error('This is an error');
  log.warn('This is a warning');
  log.attempt('This is an attempt');
  log.success('This is a success');
  log.info('This is some info');
  log.verbose('This is verbose');
  log.debug('This is a debug');
  expect(???).toEqual(10);
});

test('Logger does not print debug as standard', () => {
  let log = setLogTo();
  log.warn('This is a warning');
  log.verbose('This is a verbose statement');
  log.debug('This is a debug statement');
  expect(???).toEqual(1);
});

test('Logger does not print info when set to error', () => {
  let log = setLogTo('error');
  log.info('This is an info statement');
  log.error('This is an error')
  expect(???).toEqual(1);
});

test('Dotenv works correctly', () => {
  let log = setLogTo();
  log.debug('This is a debug');
  nodeEnvironment = 'prod';
  log.debug('This us a debug');
  expect(???).toEqual(1)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so Winston doesn't send messages to the console, or if it does it's the global console. Either way I figured that the best way around this would be to add a file logger to the console logger, subsequently reading the lines from the file rather than the console and then deleting the file after ever test. This then caused problems as standard Jest behaviour is to run its test simultaneously, so each test was attempting to access the same temporary file at the same time. This was easy to fix by passing the --runInBand option to jest in my package.json file which makes Jest run the tests sequentially.

To solve the environment variable problem, it turns out that Jest sets the NODE_ENV variable to 'test' when it starts up. I added a jest.resetModules() to the beforeEach statement allowing me to manually declare the environment at the start of each test. I stored the jest test environment in a constant at the start of the file so I could use this for the majority of the tests that did not require explicit environment variables to be set. I also created an afterAll() function to make sure that process.env was set back to the test environment for any subsequent tests.

Code:

package.json:

`"logtest": "jest --runInBand ./src/helper/tests/set-log-to.test.js",`

set-log-to.test.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const winston = require('winston');

let setLogTo = require('../set-log-to');

const { snipconDir } = require('../../constants/core-dirs');
const logTests = path.join(snipconDir, './temp/log-tests.txt');
const testEnv = process.env;

function createTestLog(level) {
  let log = setLogTo(level);
  log.add(
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: logTests,
    })
  );
  return log;
}

function allLogLevels(log) {
  log.fatal('This is fatal');
  log.caveat('This is a caveat');
  log.victory('This is a victory');
  log.error('This is an error');
  log.warn('This is a warning');
  log.attempt('This is an attempt');
  log.success('This is a success');
  log.info('This is some info');
  log.verbose('This is verbose');
  log.debug('This is a debug');
}

async function getLines() {
  let data = await fs.promises.readFile(logTests);
  let lines = data.toString().split('\n');
  lines.pop();
  return lines;
}

beforeEach(async (done) => {
  jest.resetModules();
  try {
    await fs.promises.writeFile(logTests, '');
    done();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

afterEach(async (done) => {
  try {
    await fs.promises.unlink(logTests);
    done();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to delete log-tests.js');
  }
});

afterAll(() => {
  process.env = testEnv;
});

test('When level is explicitly set to debug, all messages show', async () => {
  process.env = testEnv;
  let log = createTestLog('debug');
  allLogLevels(log);
  let lines = await getLines();
  expect(lines.length).toEqual(10);
});

test('Standard behaviour shows messages from level 2 and below', async () => {
  process.env = testEnv;
  let log = createTestLog();
  allLogLevels(log);
  let lines = await getLines();
  expect(lines.length).toEqual(5);
});

test('When explicitly set to error level, loggger displays all level 0 messages', async () => {
  process.env = testEnv;
  let log = createTestLog('error');
  allLogLevels(log);
  let lines = await getLines();
  expect(lines.length).toEqual(3);
});

test('Verbose level displays messages from level 4 and below', async () => {
  process.env = testEnv;
  let log = createTestLog('verbose');
  allLogLevels(log);
  let lines = await getLines();
  expect(lines.length).toEqual(9);
});

test('Development environment displays all messages', async () => {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'dev';
  let log = createTestLog();
  allLogLevels(log);
  let lines = await getLines();
  expect(lines.length).toEqual(10);
});

test('Production environment displays messages from level 2 and below', async () => {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'prod';
  let log = createTestLog();
  allLogLevels(log);
  let lines = await getLines();
  expect(lines.length).toEqual(5);
});
```

set-log-to.js:

```js
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, printf, errors } = format;

const cc = require('../constants/chalk-classes');
const {
  fatal,
  caveat,
  victory,
  error,
  warn,
  attempt,
  success,
  info,
  debug,
  plain,
} = cc;

const config = {
  levels: {
    fatal: 0,
    caveat: 0,
    victory: 0,
    error: 1,
    warn: 2,
    attempt: 3,
    success: 3,
    info: 3,
    verbose: 4,
    debug: 5,
  },
};

const formatting = combine(
  errors({ stack: true }),
  printf((infoObj) => {
    const { level, message } = infoObj;
    switch (level) {
      case 'fatal':
        return `${fatal(`${level}:`)} ${plain(message)}`;

      case 'caveat':
        return `${caveat(`${level}:`)} ${plain(message)}`;

      case 'victory':
        return `${victory(`${level}:`)} ${plain(message)}`;

      case 'error':
        return `${error(`${level}: ${message}`)}`;

      case 'warn':
        return `${warn(`${level}: ${message}`)}`;

      case 'attempt':
        return `${attempt(message)}`;

      case 'success':
        return `${success(message)}`;

      case 'info':
        return `${info(message)}`;

      case 'verbose':
        return `${plain(message)}`;

      case 'debug':
        return `${debug(level)}: ${plain(message)}`;
    }
  })
);

function setLevel(level) {
  if (!level) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') {
      return (level = 'debug');
    } else {
      return (level = 'warn');
    }
  } else {
    return level;
  }
}

function setLogTo(level) {
  level = setLevel(level);
  const log = createLogger({
    levels: config.levels,
    level,
    transports: [
      new transports.Console({
        format: formatting,
      }),
    ],
  });
  return log;
}

module.exports = setLogTo;
```